# jQuery: how to get the innermost dom element I'm hovering over, globally for the whole document body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseevent

I'd like to detect mouse movements over the whole document body, and be able to tell exactly which part of the DOM I'm hovering over. By "Which part" I mean the innermost DOM element that the mouse is currently over.

I could bind a hover to the whole document body, but then the $(this) would give me the $(body), not the innermost element. Or I could iterate over the whole DOM recursively and bind a hover to each elements, but that would be a serious overkill IMO.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Jasie's suggestion, I ended up using the following code:

```
var currentNode = null;
$('body').mousemove(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target) !== currentNode) {
    currentNode = $(event.target);
    console.log(currentNode);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

[jQuery's event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) should do the trick:

```
$("body").click(function(event) {
  console.log($(event.target));
});
```

Comment: Ok, figured it out, using mousemove instead of click will do it. Thanks, +1 for showing me event.target.

Answer (score -1):

:) think of all the elements, Like:

```
<div>this is div</div>
<span>this is span</span>
<p>This is p</p>
<a>this a</a>
<ul><li>this is ul li</li></ul>
<ol><li>This is ol li</li></ol>
<img src="" />
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

The textarea is to show you the result only.

```
jQuery("div,span,p,a,ul,ol,img").hover(function(){
    jQuery("#text").append(jQuery(this).html() + 
                           "<br />");
},function(){
}
);
```