# jQuery output current element hovering over using append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to output the element that I am hovering over. I do not want to output the html inside.

EG.. If I hover over

```
<i class="fa fa-wrench"><span>TEST</span></i>
```

I would be able to output something like

```
<i class="fa fa-wrench">
```

#### My attempt

I can successfully output the element into the console.log but when I do this with append I get an output of [object Object].

#### Example Code

FROM: [jQuery: how to get the innermost dom element I'm hovering over, globally for the whole document body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693015/jquery-how-to-get-the-innermost-dom-element-im-hovering-over-globally-for-the)

```
var currentNode = null;
$('body').mousemove(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target) !== currentNode) {
    currentNode = $(event.target);
    console.log(currentNode);
  }
});
```

Output Example (from console.log):

```
[i.fa.fa-wrench, context: i.fa.fa-wrench, jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function…]
```

#### My Append Code:

```
$('.specific-div).append('<div>ID:' + currentNode + '</div>');
```

Output Example (appended to .specific-div): [object Object]

Comment: You probably want JSON.stringify of the object `JSON.stringify(currentNode)`

Comment: I get the following error when doing that: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: what do you get with console.log(currentNode) at the same place you are trying JSON.stringify?

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/fSb23/

```
var currentNode = null;
$('body').mousemove(function (event) {
    if ($(event.target) !== currentNode) {
        currentNode = $(event.target).attr("id");
        console.log(currentNode);
        $('.specific-div').append(' < div > ID: ' + currentNode + ' < /div>');
  }
});
```

If you want to get the HTML and not only the ID, try it:

```
currentNode = $(event.target).html();
```

Comment: I'm trying to append the hovered element to .specific-div and not output to console.

Comment: @raison, you did tryied to output to console, it's in your code above.

Comment: Works great. New problem. Need to output the code so it doesn't load. Eg. If I hover over an image I don't want to load an image I just want to display the code. I tried wrapping with <pre> and <code> without luck. Any ideas?

Comment: @raison try `$('.specific-div').append(' < div > ID: ' + currentNode.replace(/&/g, "&amp;") .replace(/</g, "&lt;") .replace(/>/g, "&gt;") .replace(/"/g, "&quot;") .replace(/'/g, "&#039;") + ' < /div>');`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var currentNode = null;
 $('body').mousemove(function(event) {
 if ($(event.target) != currentNode) {
  currentNode = $(event.target);
  htmlText = $('<div>').append($(currentNode).clone().empty()).html();
  console.log(htmlText);
 }
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Cceb/)

Comment: I think I am nearly there with this code. I added:     $('.specific-div').append('<code class="inlinecode">' + htmlText + '</code>');  but now I have to work out how I can stop the html outputted interfering.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the class for all elements are unique, get the class of the element you hover on:

```
    var handle = document.querySelectorAll('.class-of-hovered-element')[0].outerHTML;
    console.log(handle);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For every elements, will generate a lot of output on `mousemove`

```
var currentNode = null;
$('body >').mousemove(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target) !== currentNode) {
        $('.specific-div').append($('<p>').text($('<p>').append($(this).clone().empty()).html()));
        currentNode = $(event.target);
    }
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cd4KD/2/)

For a `class` like `fa-wrench`

```
$('.fa-wrench').mouseenter(function() {
   $('.specific-div').append($('<p>').text($('<p>').append($(this).clone().empty()).html()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentNode = null;
 $('body').click(function(event) {

 if ($(event.target) !== currentNode) {

   var tag=$(event.target).prop('tagName');
   tag="<"+tag;
   $.each($(event.target).attributes, function() {
    if(this.specified) {
      tag+=this.name+"='"+this.name+"' ";
     }
 });
 tag+=">";
 console.log(tag);

 }

});
```

and add this in jquery

```
(function(old) {
$.fn.attr = function() {
if(arguments.length === 0) {
  if(this.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }

  var obj = {};
  $.each(this[0].attributes, function() {
    if(this.specified) {
      obj[this.name] = this.value;
    }
  });
  return obj;
}

 return old.apply(this, arguments);
};
})($.fn.attr);
```

It may helps try..